# C: 4 elements of an array to a DWORD

Tags: c, arrays, char, dword

Now can I copy 4 bytes (known start position, NOT 0) in an array (`char*data`) to a `DWORD`?

There are two parts to this: first, getting the 4 bytes from the array at the specified position (4 elements, each element is a char which is 1 byte in C), and then moving them to a DWORD.

I'm not sure how to do either.

Thanks!

Comment: `memcpy()`?.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `memcpy` (it requires `string.h` header):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t array[] = {
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09
    }
    uint32_t dword;
    size_t offset = 2;

    memcpy(&dword, array + offset, sizeof(dword));
    printf("Dword value = 0x%08x\n", dword);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You cannot use reliably the "ugly memcasting" thing due to alignment reasons. `memcpy` is the way to go.

Comment: There is an array not structure, so where can be a problem with alignment?

Comment: What has this to do with `struct`? The point is that there's no guarantee that `array + offset` is suitably aligned for `uint32_t`, and depending from architecture an unaligned access may result in low performance or a plain crash.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. I have changed my post.

Comment: When you add `input+offset` how does that work? Adding a number to an array pops the first two elements off?

Comment: Also you can print dwords with `%lu` which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: When you are adding something to a pointer (in C array name is a pointer to the first element of this array) you increment address which the pointer refers to - in this case you "move" to next array's elements. See "pointer arithmetic in C" in your favorite web search engine.

Comment: Does it have the endianness problem? What should I do if I want to make it works on all CPUs?

Answer (score 1):

I think below code shoudl work

```
memcpy(destination, input+offset, howMany);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is deserialization. In this case, somewhere must be specified if the data in your `char *` are big endian (start with the highest byte) or little endian (start with the lowest byte). For portable applications, BE might be the favourite.

After you have done so, your function might look like

```
uintmax_t readarrayvalue_be(const char * data, uint8_t bytes)
{
    uintmax_t value = 0;
    while (bytes) {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= *(data++) & 0xFF;
        bytes--;
    }
    return value;
}
```

while in the concrete case it might be restructured as

```
uint32_t readarrayvalue_u32_be(const char * data)
{
    uint32_t value = ((data[0] & 0xFF) << 24) | ((data[1] & 0xFF) << 16) | ((data[2] & 0xFF) << 8) | (data[3] & 0xFF);
    return value;
}
```